# Import (non-CSV) text data to PostgreSQL, which is separated via spaces and one capital letter

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, bigdata, sentiment-analysis

This is the first time I am working with SQL. I am using PostgreSQL on Windows 7 64bit.

I have the following (large) .txt file of tweets built like this:

```
T   2009-06-07 02:07:41
U   http://twitter.com/cyberplumber
W   SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
```

As you see, all three "columns" are separated in the following fashion:  `T \t` (same goes for U and W) instead of the traditional comma (`,`).
I would like to import the whole file into a SQL table with columns named `date`, `user` and `text_msg`.

I am guessing I will probably have to parse it in some way. Any ideas how to get the data into a table in the simplest and most efficient manner? Please also consider that the .txt files in question are rather huge (>4GB) and thus there is no easy way for me to edit them manually.

Comment: Is this a one off job or a regular requirement?

Comment: Also, *as always*, your version of Postgres please.

Comment: If you are importing Twitter feeds, see https://github.com/umitanuki/twitter_fdw

Answer (score 2):

Try  doing the following:

Firstly, create an appropriate table in SQL like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tweet(
 ts timestamp, -- if inserting the values as timestamps gives errors, change to 'TEXT'
 url TEXT,  --  There smarted UDTs for URL available too
 message TEXT
);
```

Then go on and try to run a standard COPY statement, something like the following:

```
COPY tweet 
FROM E'c:\\\\my dir\\\filename'  -- path of the file using the magic E for escaped text with double backslash between directory names fro Windows
FORMAT text;   -- The default delimiter  for format text is a tab
```

Finally, pray that you'll have enough memory and log spaces for > 4GB of files. For more info regarding the COPY command, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 2):

Quick&dirty hack:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE  lutser
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , ztxt text
        );

CREATE TABLE  tweetdeck
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , stamp timestamp NOT NULL
        , zurl text
        , ztxt text
        );

COPY lutser(ztxt)
FROM '/tmp/tweet.dat'
        ;

INSERT INTO tweetdeck (stamp, zurl, ztxt)
SELECT regexp_replace( t.ztxt, E'^[A-Z][ \t]*', '')::timestamp
        , regexp_replace( u.ztxt, E'^[A-Z][ \t]*', '')
        , regexp_replace( w.ztxt, E'^[A-Z][ \t]*', '')
FROM lutser t
JOIN lutser u ON u.id = t.id+1
JOIN lutser w ON w.id = t.id+2
WHERE t.id %3 = 1
AND LEFT(t.ztxt,1) = 'T' -- Should be redundant, Won't harm
AND LEFT(u.ztxt,1) = 'U'
AND LEFT(w.ztxt,1) = 'W'
        ;


SELECT * FROM lutser;
SELECT * FROM tweetdeck;
```

Results:

```
COPY 9
INSERT 0 3
 id |                                                                       ztxt                                                                       
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | T   2009-06-07 02:07:31
  2 | U   http://twitter.com/cyberplumber
  3 | W   SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
  4 | T   2009-06-07 02:07:41
  5 | U   http://twitter.com/cyberplumber
  6 | W   SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
  7 | T   2009-06-07 02:07:51
  8 | U   http://twitter.com/cyberplumber
  9 | W   SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
(9 rows)


 id |        stamp        |              zurl               |                                                                     ztxt                                                                     
----+---------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | 2009-06-07 02:07:31 | http://twitter.com/cyberplumber | SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
  2 | 2009-06-07 02:07:41 | http://twitter.com/cyberplumber | SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
  3 | 2009-06-07 02:07:51 | http://twitter.com/cyberplumber | SPC Severe Thunderstorm Watch 339: WW 339 SEVERE TSTM KS NE 070200Z - 070800Z URGENT - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUE.. http://tinyurl.com/5th9sw
(3 rows)
```